# Apps script getRowsData function deprecated?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working through a tut about a basic mail merge using google sheets https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge#section-4-more-powerful-templates .

The code sample contains the following (which I have modified):

```
function sendEmails() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Campaigns");

var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

// Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

 // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
 // it to the appropriate person.
 for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
// Get a row object
var rowData = objects[i];

// Generate a personalized email.
// Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
// the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
var emailSubject = "Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge";

MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText);
 } 
 }
```

I am unable to find a reference to 'getRowsData'  in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.

Has this been deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to scroll down a bit further.

```
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}
```

You may have missed all of this as well.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range;
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

You can use the copy icon in the upper right corner as shown in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Cooper,

The sample code on the tutorial page (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) labeled 'Full Code' does not contain the getRowsData declaration that you have posted. So, using the copy icon will not work as the copied code is missing the getRowsData function declaration. To access the getRowsData function portion of the code you need to copy the template spreadsheet and open the script editor to view the code.